# Open PHP without showing the m3u8 in the address bar

Tags: php

I'd like to open this page with the name "stream.php". However when the page is loaded m3u8 is still in the url

```
<?php header("Location: http://hlsliveamdgl8-lh.akamaihd.net/i/hlsdvrlive_1@583030/master.m3u8");?>
```

Is there any way to hide the m3u8? if it's not possible with PHP, is there another way to do it?

I use [HLS Native Playback](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/native-hls-playback/emnphkkblegpebimobpbekeedfgemhof) to play m3u8's directly from Chrome Browser (Windows 10)

Comment: Do you own the server that you're redirecting to?

Comment: m3u8 is not a streaming file per se - it's a playlist with URLs to the _real_ streams (in different qualities). Since `readfile()` works with external URLs: `<?php readfile('http://hlsliveamdgl8-lh.akamaihd.net/i/hlsdvrlive_1@583030/master.m3u8'); ?>` - be aware that anyone skilled enough could still find all the streaming URLs inside of the playlist after it's been downloaded from your server.

Comment: Readfile does not play the video, just open the content

http://ver.hol.es/read.php

any other alternative? even if it's not PHP

Comment: I'm not the server owner

Comment: Just URL rewrite with .htacess

Comment: Interesting... how to do it?

Comment: Be the server owner.  .htaccess runs on the server.   If you don't control the server and must redirect to another page, that page's URL is what you're going to see.  One idea (from a SO question with the opposite problem) is have your page act as a proxy and fetch the contents of that URL using cURL -- return that as a response instead of doing the redirect.

Comment: There's no benefit for users if you obfuscate the target URLs. That's merely misappropriation if none of the playlists belong to you.

Comment: readfile isn't supposed to play the video - it's supposed to send the same playlist with urls to the different streams - you might have to replicate the same headers you get from the akamaihd.net domain to make the player work directly but you're still just referring to a playlist full of urls. Why are you trying to hide this info from the user? To make sure they can't access the stream themselves? If you send them the stream they can access it. You can't protect yourself against that.